How to retrieve 'link clicks' metric of an Instagram account using Instagram Platform API Insights node?
I am trying to fetch data from some Instagram accounts that are on Meta Business Suite, most of them I have success to retrieve using Graph API and Instagram API, but one of them I cannot find in documentation.
It is Link Clicks on Instagram Accounts.
So I need help to retrieve this metric. Can someone help me?
I have tried these metrics: website_clicks, text_message_clicks, phone_call_clicks and profile_links_taps but none of them is the number that shows on Business Suite even adding those metrics.
I have been reading all over documentation but it is so confusing and annoying.
